# How to retain tooltip when pivoting Google Visualization DataTable

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I'm using some great code from @asgallant to pivot a Google DataTable for use in a line chart.  His code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HkjDe/

In my original DataTable I have a 4th column however that is a tooltip string.  When I pivot the table with his code my tooltip if no longer available.  I would like to use the tooltips provided and for the cells that are 'created' use some standard tooltip text. Here is what my version of the initial table setup looks like.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'A');
data.addColumn('string', 'B');
data.addColumn('number', 'C');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRows([
    [1, 'foo', 6, 't1'],
    [2, 'foo', 2, 'hello'],
    [3, 'foo', 1, 't2'],
    [4, 'foo', 3, 'test'],
    [1, 'bar', 7, 't3'],
    [2, 'bar', 3, 'again'],
    [1, 'baz', 8, 't4'],
    [2, 'baz', 4, 'and'],
    [2, 'cad', 5, 't5'],
    [3, 'cad', 6, 'again'],
    [1, 'qud', 9, 'x'],
    [5, 'qud', 1, 'z']
]);
```

Can anyone provide some assistance?

**-- UPDATE --**

Edited the initial addRows statement to be more representative of my data model.

Comment: How would you like the tooltip text to be determined?

Comment: @asgallant - Using the above pre-pivot table as an example I would like whatever is already in the tooltip column to carry over to the 'pivot' view. When a new cell has to be created, column A value 3 for bar, I would like the tooltip to be something like 'N/A'.

Comment: What about the cases where multiple cells are being combined, like the `'qud'` rows?

Comment: @asgallant - I updated the 'addRows' lines to be more inline with my model.  In my case the combination of Col A and Col B will always be unique and no combining will occur.

Answer (score 1):

In order to preserve the tooltips, you need to add tooltip columns to the view and pivot data:

```
for (var i = 0; i < distinctValues.length; i++) {
    viewColumns.push({
        type: 'number',
        label: distinctValues[i],
        calc: (function (x) {
            return function (dt, row) {
                // return values of C only for the rows where B = distinctValues[i] (passed into the closure via x)
                return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == x) ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
            }
        })(distinctValues[i])
    });
    groupColumns.push({
        column: (i * 2) + 1,
        type: 'number',
        label: distinctValues[i],
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    });
    // add columns for the tooltips
    viewColumns.push({
        type: 'string',
        calc: (function (x) {
            return function (dt, row) {
                // return values of the tooltip column only for the rows where B = distinctValues[i] (passed into the closure via x)
                return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == x) ? dt.getValue(row, 3) : null;
            }
        })(distinctValues[i])
    });
    groupColumns.push({
        column: (i * 2) + 2,
        type: 'string',
        aggregation: function (values) {
            return values.join('');
        }
    });
}
```

The group function does not handle column roles properly, so you have to set them afterwards:

```
// fix the tooltip column roles, since the group function won't create them properly
for (var i = 1; i < pivotedData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    if (pivotedData.getColumnType(i) == 'string') {
        pivotedData.setColumnProperty(i, 'role', 'tooltip');
    }
}
```

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HkjDe/23/

Comment: Thanks asgallant - two questions.  For entries that are 'created' where/how would I set a default tooltip?  Is it possible, after pivoting, to set the first column to a string so that the chart is discrete rather than continuous?

Comment: What do you mean by entries that are "created"?  Your first column can be whatever type you want - it doesn't have to be numeric.  If you want to keep it numeric for the grouping, but stringify it later, you can do that via the DataView.